# Ubuntu 12.10 TTY console (Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6]) not working

Tags: console, tty

I've been a Ubuntu user for some time now. I have a very annoying problem, I have no idea what causes it, and I haven't managed to find anything relevant after Googling like crazy.

The problem is my TTY consoles are not working. Usually, these are activated using CTRL ALT F[1-6]. It was working when I was using the Nouveau drivers, but after installing the nVidia proprietary drivers, instead of getting a terminal console I get a strange monochrome pattern that slowly fades away.

Does anyone know how to get CTRL + ALT + F[1-6] working again?

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162596/72260)?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet as I performed a clean install and am now using the Nouveau driver. I will try and re-install the proprietary nVidia drivers, and will try that answer if problem occurs again.

Comment: Tried the answer you suggested Little Ancient Forest Kami (on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and the proprietary nVidia 310.19 driver), it did not work.

Comment: [Alain Nissen's solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43386/how-do-i-get-my-blacked-out-ttys-back) worked for me. Although, with nvidia driver installed, hwinfo --frambuffer didn't work due to some dbus error. So I just went for a modestly-conservative 1024x768-24 resolution and it worked fine.

Comment: @VanessaDeagan Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: @Seth - Sorry for the very late reply. No, I'm not still experiencing that problem as I'm now using Ubuntu 16.04 :)