# Unable to switch from between Consoles

Tags: nvidia, console

I'm a novice but want to give linux a shot.  I'm using the os again after a long break. I downloaded 14.04 and really like it so far.  I just can't seem to get my gtx 750 ti card working.  I have to stop the xserver to install the driver.  When I switch to tty 3, using alt+ctl+f3, to run sh on the nvidia.run file that I downloaded, I get a blank screen.  This happens when switching between any console and requires a restart to fix.  I'm sure it's a simple chmod somewhere but I'm not familiar enough with the os to begin to figure it out.  Thanks guys for any help.

Solved: The link From Rinz in the comments resolved this issue for me Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not a chmod thing. It is your graph card problem that does not let you use a tty. Most likely you need to add a parameter to your boot, then use a tty to install the file and reboot for it to get your card to work. something similar to this: http://askubuntu.com/a/52320/15811

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success using the xorg-edgers ppa in 14.04 with my GTX 750 Ti. I am able to use tty. This is a much simpler way to update to the latest nvidia drivers than the method you are currently using.

The commands below are for the latest beta drivers, if you want the latest stable branch instead of the beta, just replace "337" with "334"--both officially support the 750 Ti.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-337
sudo apt-get install nvidia-337-uvm
```

PPA info here: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa
and here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers
The "umbrella" package is called nvidia-graphics-drivers-337

Note that this PPA will upgrade multiple Ubuntu packages related to X. If you choose to remove the PPA or upgrade the distro, you will probably want to run ppa-purge first--as noted on the Launchpad page.

When using the xorg-edgers PPA,you will also receive automatic updates to the nvidia driver series you selected--usually in just a few days after their release.